# Why does this 7-Segment Display not function properly?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, display, 7segmentdisplay, decoder

I've provided details in image.

Although, I'll once again provide in text:

> IC        : 74LS47N (Binary to 7-Seg Display)
>
> 7 Segment : Common Anode
>
> M.S.B     : D
>
> L.S.B     : A

This is how absurd OUTPUT is displayed by 7-Seg Disp:

> **INPUT** *(D,C,B,A to IC)*___**OUTPUT** *(7-SEG DISP)*
>
> *DCBA*
>
> **0000**_______________**2**
>
> **0001**_______________**3**
>
> **0010**_______________**2**
>
> **0011**_______________**3**
>
> **0100**_______________**b**
>
> **0101**_______________**7**
>
> **0110**_______________**b**
>
> **0111**_______________**7**
>
> **1000**_______________**c**
>
> **1001**_______________**ɔ** <--- (-_- !) lol

[image]

I've edited the pics, so that you may see the wirings clearly.
As you can see the problem in the image itself,(i.e. the output of 7-Seg does not matches with the input to the IC).

> **Note: There is no problem with my connections. They are exactly as shown below:**

**I did the connections 5 to 6 times all over again, but all it shows is absurd and illogical results**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like B is stuck high. Have you verified the voltage?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I did't get what you are trying to say?
B(as of input) , it can be changed mechanically(as you may see the inputs are below IC provided with Male-to-Male wires colored YELLOW,ORANGE,GREY and WHITE.)

As of verifying voltage, ill give you one example:
When input is 0000 to IC, It gives OUTPUT 2
here for IC(i checked using multimeter and it shows)-
a-4.67
b-4.70
c-0.00
d-4.69
e-4.71
f-0.00
g-4.68
(these are voltages before going through resistors - to - 7Seg)

Comment: He said that because if you look at your "absurd" output, it would not be inconceivable to think that input B is being held high. When you are setting the inputs with the wires, make sure they are making contact and that you are not creating shorts. Use a DVM in continuity mode to check the connections before powering on (for the correct inputs and in between inputs for shorts).

Comment: Maybe pin 1 of the chip is folded underneath.

Comment: No that's not the case, i tried with other ICs as well. Even changed their positions on bread board.

Comment: Measure the voltage on pin 1 of the 7447 (right on the chip) - it appears to be stuck High.  Make sure that you can set it to Low (0 volts, ground) when you want it Low.

Comment: Well, _if_ your connections are as in the schematic, please explain to me, how the Vcc potential reaches to the second lowes row in the lower left corner in Pic 1.

Comment: I see. The problem was that my bit 1 was hard coded to 1.this solved my problem. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 74LS47 shows the following:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccl}
D & C & B & A \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow 3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow 6 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow 7 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow 8 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow 9 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow c \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow ɔ \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow u \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow 3~horizontal~lines \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow broken~6 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow 
\end{array}
$$

You show:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccl}
D & C & B & A \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow 3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow b \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow 7 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \rightarrow b \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \rightarrow 7 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \rightarrow c \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \rightarrow ɔ
\end{array}
$$

This makes me think your B term is hard-coded to a 1 and that you are misinterpreting a 6 as a b.

Check your B term going into the 74LS47. If it is working, then I think your 74LS47 has a damaged B input.

EDIT: Good to hear that you got it working!

Comment: Outclassed, you guys were absolutely correct. The INPUT B was Hard-coded to 1. It took me a while to understand how to figure that out, but my sir explained it to me and got my doubts cleared. You guys are angels. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 7):

From your table, it's pretty obvious that bit 1 is stuck on.  Note that 0000 displays like 0010, 0101 like 0111, etc.  This is likely a wiring error, probably a floating input.

Comment: Yeah it's working now, thank you, you guys are amazing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your breadboard is not wired properly. The Vcc and GND rails are in the middle of the board connected horizontally only once. You have to remember, that the two rows of the board are not connected by default. You have to place a wire between the two rows of each supply potential. Especially your Vcc and GND connections in the lower left of the board seem not to be connected to ground.

Comment: I'm well aware of the connections. I've properly connected the GND by placing wire between them. See pic 1.On the right of 7seg you can see a black wire. That's for positive supply.. In pic 2 at bottom most you can see a tiny black connection. That's for connecting to ground, but that's only for below row. I've not done that for above row for Vcc

Comment: Well, I can't see, where the GND, the yellow, white and gray lines should be plugged to comes from. Same for Vcc and the orange wire.

Comment: Verify your Vcc in the lower left line of the board.

Comment: @NitishPrajapati: I also don't see where the VCC and GND pins are connected together. You said you are "well aware of the connections". I just want to verify **what** you are aware of. Are you aware you have 8 power strips? Or do you think there are only 4? The 8 power strips - top first row left, top first row right, top second row left top second row right, bottom first row left, bottom first row right, bottom second row left and bottom second row right. It seems you have connected top first row left and right together and you have connected bottom second row left and right together

Comment: @NitishPrajapati ... but I don't see where you are connecting top second row to the first row and I don't see where you are connecting the bottom first row to the second row